# Search engine software specialized in serving links that work with a no-script browser

Tags: javascript, web-browser, search-engine

Is there a search engine software that gives results usable without JavaScript or other scripts enabled?

This would be great for the following situations:

- Browser with JavaScript, Java applets, ActiveX, Flash, ... disabled
- Use through limited devices such as e-ink eBook readers (Kobo,...), server console (lynx, links,...), minimalist situations

Ideally, such search engine software should have the following features:

A. Add a link with:

1. URL
2. Title
3. Description
4. Keywords
5. Category
6. Whether to crawl for sub pages
7. Contains non mandatory:

   - JavaScript
   - Java applet
   - ActiveX
   - Flash
   - Cookies
   - Static graphics (images)
   - Dynamic graphics (video)
   - Audio
   - CSS
   - Redirects
   - Other non-HTML/text content
8. Whether content is available through HTTP, HTTPS or both
9. Language

B. For each URL entry records:

1. History of changes
2. Crawl on demand
3. Links parsed
4. Update fields depending on crawler analysis

C. Also add a whole site through a sitemap.xml

D. Search with:

1. No need for any other technology than HTML/text
2. Filter and sort based on the fields in section A.
3. No tracking/logging of visits
4. Choice whether to use HTTP or HTTPS
5. Interface language choice

E. Community:

1. Wiki way to edit the links and their fields
2. Comments on each link

If technically compatible, I would be happy to host such a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As I could not find any fitting solution, I developed my own available here:
https://noscript.jod.li

Answer (score 0):

This question, as currently written, will only meet our community's on-topic criteria if a search engine can be considered a 'web-app', which feels like a bit of a stretch to me.

Regardless, to help you out *(which is the primary function of our community!)*, I found  a good answer for you.  DuckDuckGo has an excellent search engine web-based GUI that does not require any JavaScript at all.  It is freely available here:

https://lite.duckduckgo.com/lite

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RockPaperLz . Sorry for the potentially off topic question. I realize that my question was not clear enough. Indeed, duckduckgo has two interfaces working without JavaScript (lite and HTML) while the results given by those two interfaces still require potentially JavaScript. What I am looking for is a specialized search engine that only serves non-js requiring links. The difference is more on the content than the presentation. If not here, do you know where I could ask this question?

Comment: Maybe I could rephrase my question as follows for it to be understandable and on-topic?
"Search engine software specialized for browsers without JavaScript"
Because, if I can host the search engine software on one of my servers, I'm happy to do it.

Comment: Ah! I see what you are asking now! :)  You want the *sites in the results* to only be sites that work without JavaScript.  Wow, such a search engine would be wonderful!  I've never heard of such a thing, but it's a great idea.  I think if you tweak your question to add clarity and include that you are willing to host the search engine software yourself, it will be a valuable question to our community.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do my best to rephrase :)